# Finding inverse function with derivative

Tags: calculus

Let $f = 9e^x + e^{-x}$. I want to find inverse function ($f^{-1}(y)$). 
I notice that $f'' = f$ and trying using formula $(f^{-1})'(y) = (f'(x))^{-1}$, but it gives no benefit to me..

Comment: Are you trying to find the inverse (ie, write down a formula) or show that it exists?

Comment: please clarify what you want.

Comment: Trying to find inverse.

Comment: The inverse does not exist since the function is not injective.

Comment: f is a variable not a function but f(x) or f(y) is. you can't find inverse of a variable

Comment: Inverse functions on monotonic areas(pardon my english).

Comment: @Bot How does that contribute to the question? I mean notation and nomenclature is always disputable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to go to second derivative at all.I shall outline a *general procedure* to find inverse function through the first derivative.

Your question relates to relationship between derivatives of given and inverse functions.

The procedure is to replace $ y^{'}$ by $ \dfrac {1}{y^{'}}, $ *alongwith* interchanging two variables.

Given relation:

$$ y= 9\, e^x + e^{-x} ... (1*) $$

You can straight away swap x and y to get

$$ x= 9\, e^y + e^{-y} ... (2*) $$

but that is not what you want.

Differentiating (1*)

$$ y^{'}(x)= 9\, e^x - e^{-x} ... (3*) $$

*Changing derivatives and swapping variables,*

$$ \dfrac{1}{Y^{'}(x)} = 9\, e^ Y - e^{-Y} $$ i.e.,

$$ Y^{'}(x) = \dfrac{1}{(9 e^{Y} - e^ {-Y} )} (4*) $$ ( I have capitalized x,y so as to distinguish between the original and inverse functions)

Integrating,

$$ Y = log \dfrac{ [ (X+c) \pm \sqrt{ (X+c)^2 -36}\,]} {18} ( 5*) $$

with an arbitrary constant of integration c.

When c =0, the above ( 5*) is nothing but (2*) when quadratic equation for y is solved in terms of x.

There is *no way* you can avoid the constant of integration as long the procedure is through the derivative.

EDIT2:

A much simpler example :$$  y = x^2 +1, y'(x) = 2 x; 1/ Y^{'}(X)= 2 Y ; dX = 2 Y dY $$

Integrate $$  X= Y^2 + c ; BC:\, X= 1, Y=0 , \rightarrow c= 1; Y = \sqrt{X-1}. $$

Direct without integration: $$   X= Y^2 + 1; Y = \sqrt{X-1}.$$

EDIT3:

Using this procedure it is instructive to verify that the Tresca Ellipse represented by differential equation

$$   \dfrac{dy}{dx}= \dfrac{y-2 x}{2 y -x}  $$

is its own inverse function.

Answer (score 2):

given $y=9e^x+e^{-x}$ set $e^x=t$ and solve the equation
$$9t^2-yt+1=0$$ for $t$

Comment: Very nice approach!

Comment: But how to solve it using this formula
$(f^{-1})'(y) = (f'(x))^{-1}$

Comment: @user2715119: That formula is helpful for finding the derivative of the inverse function, but not necessarily helpful for finding the inverse function itself.

Comment: @user2715119: This formula helps along with swapping x,y and to integrate further as shown.